# Axios params returns data inside an object instead of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When using axios.get without the params all data is returned inside of array like it is supposed to be, but when I use params all objects are returned inside an object and I'cant map it. How can put all objects inside of array? If I try to put it inside of array it only puts the object that contains all the objects I need.

```
axios
  .get("http://api.digiart.lt/items/", { params: { category: "latte" } })
  .then((response) => {
    let coffee = response.data;
    this.props.onLoadData(coffee);
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

returns like this

```
{…}
count: 10,
items: Object { 0: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, … },
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

supposed to be like this

```
Array(41) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

Comment: that's not related with the axios you have to send as an array from 'http://api.digiart.lt/items/ this get api

Comment: do you know how to take all of those objects out of the object and put them inside of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default response from the `http://api.digiart.lt/items/` API

Use `Object.keys` to map it to an array.

```js
// Request -> http://api.digiart.lt/items?category=latte
var response = {
  "items": {
    "0": {
      "title": "Abbey's White Chocolate Latte",
      "description": "I created this recipe for my little sister, Abbey, who`s a latte fanatic. She was blown away, and drained it to the last drop! This makes one VERY large, indulgent latte, and could probably serve two. Enjoy!\n\nIngredients:\n1 1\/2 cups milk\n1 tablespoon heavy cream\n1\/8 teaspoon vanilla extract\n1 tablespoon white sugar\n1\/2 cup brewed espresso\n1\/4 cup white chocolate chips, chopped",
      "url": "https:\/\/www.allrecipes.com\/recipe\/137332\/abbeys-white-chocolate-latte\/",
      "category": "latte",
      "date": "2018-05-31",
      "img": "https:\/\/images.media-allrecipes.com\/userphotos\/560x315\/2107268.jpg"
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "Brown Sugar-Caramel Latte",
      "description": "Sometimes coffee is a dessert in itself. This is one of my favorite morning treats to make a Monday seem less intimidating. You'll need a battery-powered milk frother or it's just not the same.\n\nIngredients:\n1 tablespoon brown sugar\n1\/4 cup half-and-half\n1 tablespoon caramel ice cream topping\n3\/4 cup hot, brewed coffee",
      "url": "https:\/\/www.allrecipes.com\/recipe\/139119\/brown-sugar-caramel-latte\/",
      "category": "latte",
      "date": "2017-08-22",
      "img": "https:\/\/images.media-allrecipes.com\/userphotos\/560x315\/707064.jpg"
    }
    // .. More items
  }
}

var arr = []
Object.keys(response.items).forEach(key => arr.push(response.items[key]))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Great answer! I only had to do response.data.items instead of response.items . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
axios.get('http://api.digiart.lt/items/',
        { params: 
            { category:"latte" }} )
    .then(response => {
        let coffee = Object.keys(response.items).map(i => response.items[i])
```

Comment: Great answer! I only had to do response.data.items instead of response.items . Thank you!